# Getting contract address

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I saw an example about this, while was searching it on the internet.

I want to deploy a new contract which is ProjectContract. However, I could not get contract address as below. I think this is for old version.

```
address newProjectAddress = new ProjectContract(name, description, requiredPrice, msg.sender);
```

And the error message is:
[image: This the error message]

How can I do that for the new versions?

Comment: Have a look at interface like https://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating `new <contractName>`, it returns the contract instance. You can cast it to the `address` type and get the contract address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract ProjectContract {
    constructor (string memory name, string memory description, uint256 requiredPrice, address owner) {
    }
}

contract MyContract {
    event LogAddress(address _address);
    
    function createProjectContract(string memory name, string memory description, uint256 requiredPrice) external {
        ProjectContract newProjectInstance = new ProjectContract(name, description, requiredPrice, msg.sender);
        address newProjectAddress = address(newProjectInstance); // here
        emit LogAddress(newProjectAddress);
    }
}
```